# Are all disjoint events dependent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is a basic question about probability theory.

My reasoning goes as follows:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, the probability they both happen is their multiplication: 
   $$\Pr(A \text{ and } B) = \Pr(A) \times \Pr(B)$$
2. If their marginal probability is not impossible, also their product is non-zero:
   $$\Pr(A) > 0,\, \Pr(B) > 0 \implies \Pr(A \text{ and } B) > 0$$
3. Hence, independent events cannot be disjoint
4. Hence, only dependent events can be disjoint
5. Hence, all disjoint events are dependent.

Can you help me point out the error in my argument?

Comment: Disjoint events are definitely not independent, you are right: knowing that one happens **prevents** the other from happening, so they are not independent.

Comment: Technically, an event of probability 0 is independent of any other event, and it could also be disjoint from the other event.

Comment: You are right as long as A and B have positive probabilities

Comment: So, if P(A and B) = 0 [ = disjoint], how can I calculate P(A|B), since they need to be dependent?

Comment: if $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(B)>0$ then $P(A|B)=0$.

Comment: Isn't $P(A|B)=0$ a way to express that A and B are independent?

Comment: My bad, $P(A|B)=P(A)$ means A and B are independent. $P(A|B)=0$ is a way to express A and B are disjoint. Now all is clear, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as A and B are mutually exclusive and sum up to 1 or 100%,  P(A) + P(B) = 1.
Example : You are either dead or alive. The chance of being alive or dead always sums up tp 1 or 100%, no matter what condition you live in.